# Riemann sum with circles!

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

My friend and I were talking about Riemann sum and friend suggested that all rectangles would be replaced by circles this is the formula I came up with:
$$
\lim _{n\ \to\ \infty}\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}\pi\,{\rm f}^{2}\left(\, i\,\right)
$$
Is this formula right and if so does this formula work for all Riemann integrable functions ?. I can visualize it failing for a straight line. What is the error bound for this formula in terms of the number of circles ?. I am very confident that it is related to the maximum curvature somehow. I should note here that circles may not stack on each other. This would mean that for a straight line it would probably fail.

Comment: I think that it would approximate a bit better if you use $f(i)$ as the diameter of your circle instead of the radius. So use the sum of $\pi (\frac{1}{2}f(i))^2$.

Comment: You probably mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \pi f(x_i)^2 \Delta x_i$, if you're trying to make a variant of the usual Riemann sum. It's fine to write down mathematical objects. But the point of a Riemann sum is that it approximates (and, in the limit, equals) the area under a curve. It's extremely unlikely that a randomly chosen variant is going to have any similar point.

Comment: Ok I will make changes, mr mapierece271, if nessecary

Comment: Why would we need a dx we are already computing the area here I don't think we need to multiply it my a width. I will consider the changes.

Comment: You need a width. You are adding up the areas of the center an infinite number of times, so what you've written will never be finite.

Comment: This looks like the way we compute volume of revolution using pancakes...except you need a thickness of a pancake in there somewhere.

Comment: good to know I will make the edit.

Comment: Since the rectangles have different width and height (with width going to zero), an approximation with ellipses (with the minor axis going to zero) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I've just written a paper on this subject for class. My answer is a bit different from yours, because I am allowing circles to stack on each other.

Rectangular Riemann sums take the form $$\sum_{i=0}^n f(a+i\Delta x)\Delta x $$ when given a function $f(x)$, divided into $n$ partitions, bounded between $ a \text{ and } b.  \Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n} $. Multiplying the function value and the width of the partition gives us the area of the rectangle that is being created.

For circles, we can set the diameter of the circle equal to the partition width, and then stack the circles up to the height of the function value. We can then get the area of the stack by finding the number of circles which will fit under the curve and then multiplying by the area of a partition-diameter circle.

$$ A_{stack} = \frac{f(a+n_i\Delta x)}{\Delta x} \times \frac{\pi \Delta x^2}{4} $$

Substituting $ \Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n} $ back in, and summing up to the number of partitions, we eventually come to this simplification:

$$ A_{total} = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{f(a+i(\frac{b-a}{n}))(b-a)\pi}{4n} $$

Any area generated by this sum is, interestingly, 78% of the value given by a rectangular sum. This is because a circle has 78% of the area of a square with the same radius (a line from the middle of the rectangle to a side, which is perpendicular to that side). This calculation is with givens $ f(x)=x^2+1, [a,b] = [0,1], n = 10 $.

$$ A_{circle} = \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{10} \frac{f(\frac{i}{10})\pi}{40} = \frac{\pi}{40} + \frac{1.01\pi}{40} + \dots + \frac{2\pi}{40} = \frac{297}{800}\pi \approx 1.166 $$

$$ A_{rectangle} = \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{10} \frac{f(\frac{i}{10})}{10} = \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1.01}{10} + \dots + \frac{2}{10} = 1.485 $$

$$ \frac{1.166}{1.485} \approx 0.7851 $$

When you take the sum to infinity, it converges at a value that is 78% of the real value.

$$ A_{total} = \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\pi}{4n} = \frac{(\left(\frac{0}{n}\right)^2+1)\pi}{4n} + \dots + \frac{(\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)^2+1)\pi}{4n} $$
      $$ = \frac{\pi}{4n}\left[\left(\left(\frac{0}{n}\right)^2 + 1 \right) + \left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 + 1 \right) + \dots + \left(\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)^2 + 1 \right)\right] $$
      $$ = \frac{\pi}{4n}\left[\left(\left(\frac{0}{n}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 + \dots + \left(\frac{n}{n}\right)^2\right) + n \right] $$
      $$ = \frac{\pi}{4n}\left[\left(\frac{0}{n}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 + \dots + \left(\frac{n}{n}\right)^2 \right] + \frac{\pi}{4} $$
      $$ = \frac{\pi}{4n^3}\left[ \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \right] + \frac{\pi}{4} $$
      $$ = \frac{8\pi n^2 + 3\pi n + \pi}{24n^2} = \frac{8\pi}{24} + \frac{3\pi}{24n} + \frac{\pi}{24n^2} $$
      $$ = \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{8\pi}{24} + \frac{3\pi}{24n} + \frac{\pi}{24n^2}\right) = \frac{1}{3}\pi \approx 1.0472 $$